Implementing crypto hash - Node.js 22 - Angular 18
I already searched within Stack Overflow and in Google for solutions, but none of the solutions work, I always get following error :
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in ....

I did already:

npm update
ng update

auth.service.ts : ( not the html component - not in the browser - hidden authentication service )
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { scrypt, randomBytes, timingSafeEqual } from "crypto";

const keyLength = 32;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

constructor() {};

async login( username: string, password: string ) {
  if ( await AuthService.compare(username, await AuthService.hash(password))) {
    localStorage.setItem('STATE', 'true');
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
  
async logout() {
    localStorage.setItem('STATE', 'false');

    return true;
}
  
isLoggedIn() {
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('STATE');
  if (loggedIn == 'true')
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

/**
 * Has a password or a secret with a password hashing algorithm (scrypt)
 * @param {string} password
 * @returns {string} The salt+hash
 */
static async hash( password: string ): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // generate random 16 bytes long salt - recommended by NodeJS Docs
      const salt = randomBytes(16).toString("hex");

      scrypt(password, salt, keyLength, (err, derivedKey) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          // derivedKey is of type Buffer
          resolve(`${salt}.${derivedKey.toString("hex")}`);
      });
    });
  };

/**
* Compare a plain text password with a salt+hash password
* @param {string} password The plain text password
* @param {string} hash The hash+salt to check against
* @returns {boolean}
*/
static async compare( password: string, hash: string ): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const [salt, hashKey] = hash.split(".");
      // we need to pass buffer values to timingSafeEqual
      const hashKeyBuff = Buffer.from(hashKey, "hex");
      scrypt(password, salt, keyLength, (err, derivedKey) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          // compare the new supplied password with the hashed password using timeSafeEqual
          resolve(timingSafeEqual(hashKeyBuff, derivedKey));
      });
    });
  };

}

Crypto module is built-in in Node.js 22.4.1 which I use for my Angular 18:
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptoscryptpassword-salt-keylen-options-callback
The solution is not:

npm install crypto (old way)
not using Crypto-JS
No errors shown in Visual Studio Code (but errors show up when doing "Start debugging")


Is this piece of code executed server side? Probably not, in browser you don't have something like crypto module, but you have https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API, that is also available in Node and might be a good choice.

Also, node since version 15 supports the web crypto api. https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptowebcrypto

You'll need to use something available in browsers like the Web Crypto API.
Hashing could look something like:
static async hash(password: string): Promise<string> {
  const salt = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16))
  const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    new TextEncoder().encode(password),
    { name: "PBKDF2" },
    false,
    ["deriveBits"])
  const derivedBits = await crypto.subtle.deriveBits({
    name: "PBKDF2",
    salt,
    iterations: 100000,
    hash: "SHA-256"
  }, key, 256)
  return `${this.bufferToHex(salt)}.${this.bufferToHex(derivedBits)}`
}

Comparing could look something like:
static async compare(password: string, hash: string): Promise<boolean> {
  const [saltHex, storedHashHex] = hash.split('.')
  const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    new TextEncoder().encode(password),
    { name: "PBKDF2" },
    false,
    ["deriveBits"]
  )
  const derivedBits = await crypto.subtle.deriveBits({
    name: "PBKDF2",
    salt: this.hexToBuffer(saltHex),
    iterations: 100000,
    hash: "SHA-256"
  }, key, 256)
  return storedHashHex === this.bufferToHex(derivedBits)
}

Shouldn't need to import anything for this to work. I'm not a security expert so can't guarantee the security of these algorithms, but PBKDF2 is generally considered acceptable for password hashing.
